# HTTP request to authenticate user in Artifactory

Tags: python, http

I would like to do an http request using a pyhton script.

1. to authenticate a user using it's email and Token-Reference.
2. after authentication succeeds, I would like to continue by downloading a file which exists in the Jfrog Artifactory. Preferbally using the requests library.

I searched the web a lot, but didn't find something relevant.

Thanks

Comment: That depends on how the website authenticates it's users, is it an API (Token, Header, Certificate, etc...) or do you need to login first in a login portal? I find it HARD to believe you couldn't find anything related to authentication in the web.

Comment: How can i know which api i should send for authorization?  I think that's my main issue.

Comment: I have no idea, check the website for documentation or if they even have an API, I found this on google but I have no idea if that's what you want https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/artifactory-rest-apis

Comment: I'm trying to do it by rightclick + inspect and follow the http requests

Comment: That's another way. Might want to use BurpSuite, Fiddler or Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use post of request library for sending username and password of JFrog. Its suggestion worked with JFrog Rest API. For example:

```
import requests

request = requests.post(
    repository_api_url,
    auth=(jfrog_username, jfrog_password),
    verify=False,
)
```